# JQgrid accessing value from another column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jqgrid

I'm using JQgrid to draw a table in my jsp. For one of the columns, I have a custom formatter:

```
function profileConsentFmatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
    if (options.colModel[12] == "CORPADMIN") {
        return "Company Admin";
    } else if (cellvalue == "true") {
        return "Yes";
    } else {
        return "Pre GDPR";
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want the value of this column, to depend on the value of another column. How do I do that? I tried different methods from the documentation and they don't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `rowObject` parameter. It has all the data for that row but the rowObject format depends on the format of data it received from the server.

```
function profileConsentFmatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
    if (rowObject.AdminType == "CORPADMIN") {//assuming JSON here
        return "Company Admin";
    } else if (cellvalue) {
        return "Yes";
    } else {
        return "Pre GDPR";
    }
}
```

This should work.